# How does subprocess decide what encoding to write to file objects that accept str only

Tags: python, subprocess

I found the following behavior quite confusing:

```
Python 3.7.2 (default, Feb 12 2019, 08:15:36) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.write(b'')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
>>> subprocess.run('echo', stdout=sys.stdout)

CompletedProcess(args='echo', returncode=0)
```

`sys.stdout` doesn't accept binary. I didn't specify an encoding on my `subprocess` call, that means that it should be streaming binary. How did subprocess know not to feed the file object binary data in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how subprocesses work. The subprocess does not interact with the `sys.stdout` object - that object only exists in python, and only in *your* process.

To understand what's really happening, you first need to know how the OS handles IO. At the OS level, each opened file (or pipe) is assigned an ID - this is called a [file handle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor). For example, the handle for `stdout` is conventionally the number `1`:

```
>>> sys.stdout.fileno()
1
```

When you start a subprocess, only this file handle is passed to the subprocess. The subprocess does *not* have access to the `sys.stdout` file object. All the subprocess can do is to write bytes to the file handle it received. (At the OS level there are only bytes, no text.) You can't force the subprocess to use a specific encoding.

When you pass an `encoding` argument to `subprocess.run`, that encoding is only used to encode text you send to the subprocess or receive from the subprocess. It does not affect the subprocess itself, it only affects how *your* process communicates with the subprocess.

Comment: In fact, you cannot pass any non file descriptor based file object to subprocess; for example, `subprocess.run('echo', stdout=io.BytesIO())` will fail with `io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno`

Comment: Another interesting consequence of this fact is that the buffer of the file object you pass is NOT implicitly flushed. So if you have `print("A", end="", file=sys.stdout);
subprocess.run (("echo", "B"), stdout=sys.stdout)` the A will not get flushed before  the subprocess runs.